# Prevent _id from being populated by just one schema

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

So I have the following schema:

```
var List = new Schema(
    {
        item_details_template: {
            default: [
                {
                    "title": "Name",
                    "content": "",
                    "hidden": false,
                    "order": 0,
                    "the_type": "text"
                },
                {
                    "title": "Price",
                    "content": "",
                    "hidden": false,
                    "order": 1,
                    "the_type": "text"
                },
                {
                    "title": "Company",
                    "content": "",
                    "hidden": false,
                    "order": 2,
                    "the_type": "text"
                }
            ],
            type: [Item_Detail]
        }
    }
)
```

However, I don't want ONLY this schema (subdocument) to not create `_id` fields. How do I do this? I know you can change the original schema itself, but it's being used by other Schemas, where I would like the `_id` to be populated.

Answer (score 3):

To suppress `_id` on the `item_detail_template`, you need to restructure the way you create subdocument as follows

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");

var subSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    //your subschema content
},{ _id : false });

var schema = mongoose.Schema({
    // schema content
    subSchemaCollection : [subSchema] // item_details_template
});

var model = mongoose.model('tablename', schema);
```

Comment: yeah, that was one way I was thinking I'd have to do it by.

Comment: I'm seeing if there are other solutions first.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to suppress `_id` on the `item_detail_template` in the `List` schema only:

```
var List = new Schema(
    {
        item_details_template: {
            _id:false, // should supress _id property
            default: [
            ...
```

Comment: it's still generating it.

Answer (score 0):

```
var widgetSchema = new Schema({ ... attributes ... }, { versionKey: false });
```

Comment: I don't think you can globally disable them, but can only do it per Schema. You can read more about Schema's options from below link. You might also find the Schema set method helpful.

Comment: Please don't use comments to clarify, [edit] your answer instead. Comments may or may not be shown initially. They do appear in order of votes. You also cannot format code properly in comments.